# increase/decrease a variable with notify/notifyAll

Tags: java, concurrency

Let's suppose I got 2 threads.

Each thread executes for 100 times.

- Thread 1 decreases a variable by 10.
- Thread 2 increases a variable by 10.

What's the difference between using notify() or notifyAll() in the increase(...) method?

```
class Monitor1 {
private volatile int compar;

public Monitor1(int val) {
    compar = val;
}

synchronized public void decrease(int amount) {
    while (amount > compar) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    compar -= amount;
    System.out.println("variable=" + compar);
}

synchronized public void increase(int amount) {
    compar += amount;
    notifyAll();
    System.out.println("variable=" + compar);
}
}
```

I'm checking the output that I get using notify() or notifyAll() but I can't come to any conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

notify() awakes only one waiting thread, and  notifyAll() awakes all. This program should always use notifyAll(). Otherwise, a situation can occur when a monitor has enough tokens but method decrease() does not return:

```
Monitor1 monitor = new Monitor1(0);
Thread c1 = new Thread(()->monitor.decrease(1));
Thread c2 = new Thread(()->monitor.decrease(1));
c1.start(); c2.start();
Thread.sleep(100);
monitor.increase(2);
```

If notify() is used, only one consumer would continue execution (which is wrong),  and when notifyAll() is used, both consumers would proceed (which is correct).